# The difference between "Subset" and "SubsetRandomSampler"

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, pytorch, subset

Recently, I am trying to solve K-fold Cross Validation problem by using `Subset` and `SubsetRandomSampler` method.

When I using the `Subset` method, the first epoch accuracy for CIFAR10 dataset is **88%** , However, when I using the `SubsetRandomSampler` method, first epoch accuracy for CIFAR10 dataset only got **16%**. It really confuse my and I have no idea. Does anybody know about that? Thanks a lot.

**The code for `Subset` method:**

```
 for fold,(trainLoader,valLoader) in enumerate(kf.split(trainSet)):

      trainSetBasic = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainSet, trainLoader)
      valSetBasic = torch.utils.data.Subset(trainSet, valLoader)

      dataloaders = {
  'train': DataLoader(trainSetBasic, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=2),
  'val': DataLoader(valSetBasic, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
  }
```

**The code for `SubsetRandomSampler` method:**

```
for fold,(trainLoader,valLoader) in enumerate(kf.split(trainSet)):

      train_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(trainLoader)
      val_subsampler = torch.utils.data.SubsetRandomSampler(valLoader)

      dataloaders = {
  'train': DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sampler=train_subsampler, shuffle=False, num_workers=2),
  'val': DataLoader(trainSet, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, sampler=val_subsampler, shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
  }
```

And the code for other parts are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the difference between both codes is the manual shuffling of the indices.

How is your Dataset defined - are the classes sorted internally? If it is, using `SubsetRandomSampler` you would only pass the first classes to `train_subsampler` and the last classes to the `val_subsampler`. That would explain the bad accuracy.

Comment: `train_set = datasets.CIFAR10("./sample_data", train=True, download=True, transform=images_transform['train'])` 
Thanks for your reply. That's how I get the CIFAR10 dataset, Is this what you mean by 「classes sorted internally」?

Comment: First, what is this `trainSet` that you passed to the `dataloaders` in `SubsetRandomSampler` method?

Comment: I am sorry, it was typing mistake. trainSet is the train_set.  The code should be `trainSet = datasets.CIFAR10("./sample_data", train=True, download=True, transform=images_transform['train'])`

Comment: According to the [CIFAR10 reference](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) the dataset is already in random order, and by using `SubsetRandomSampler ` you are sampling elements randomly - so as long as I understood, using the second method, your model is only **seeing a portion of your training data**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really help. By the way, if I want to use ImageFolder to import my own dataset, like this `dataset_train: datasets.ImageFolder(train_dir, transform=images_transform['train'])`, should I still use the first method, or both methos can works.

Comment: Regarding data loading torchvision datasets, here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/algocompretto/f2644c2e2327a7b1c00e042209e3197b) that may help you!

Comment: Thanks again! It really helps.